# How to popup visible from code behind and catch its events?

Tags: c#, css, popup, modal-dialog, modal-window

I'm developing a web forms application in .NET, however I'm more well versed in back end programming rather than front end. I need a pop-up window which is meant to show up and collect the experience from the user with the application, done by three image buttons, each with their own event.

For this purpose, I found a CSS based modal window that I modified so that it looks like the pop-up I want. The html for this is as follows:

```
<a href="#test" class="btn btn-big">Modal!</a>
<a href="#" runat="server" id="test" class="modal" aria-hidden="true"></a> 
<div runat="server" id="dia" class="modal-dialog">
<h3>How was your experience?</h3>
<div class="modal-body">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" imageURL="~/resources/smileyface.png" runat="server" Width="75" Height="75" />    
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" imageURL="~/resources/neutralface.png" runat="server" Width="75" Height="75" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" imageURL="~/resources/sadface.png" runat="server" Width="75" Height="75" />
</div>
</div>
```

This produces a button named Modal (first a tag) and opens the window with a nice transition specified by the CSS.

I want to be able to make the pop-up visible from code behind. Something like

```
popup.Visible=true;
```

And to be able to catch the OnClick events of the three image buttons.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an advice with jquery UI Dialog as an example:

To call it from code behind you can use:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"anyKey",
"$('#dialog').dialog();$('#dialog').parent().appendTo($('form:first'));",true);
```

It is important to append it to the form in order to make the OnClick Events work.

Inside your Dialog you can declare your asp serverside controls, like your imagebutton.

```
     <div id="dialog" title="My Dialog">
     <p>I Am a Dialog</p>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn1" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtn1_Click" />
     </div>
```

The OnClick Event will be catched.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've attempted to add the same line of code with changing #dialog to #dia as my div's ID. But still when I try to make it show using your line it's not doing anything. Any idea why? :/

Comment: What js library are you using for your dialog?

Comment: I'm not using a library. T_T Can you recommend a dll? If you mean for the dialog itself, it's a CSS only dialog. No JS.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like visibility:none and change that css property with js, or just give jQuery UI a try.